# Blackberry - get image data from bitmap

Tags: image, blackberry, java-me

how to get image data from a bitmap image ? i searched, but i cant find a solution

```
int height=bmp.getHeight();

int width=bmp.getWidth();
int[] rgbdata = new int[width*height];
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
//Graphics g = new Graphics(bmp);
bmp.getARGB(rgbdata,0,width,0,0,width,height);

for (int i = 0; i < rgbdata.length ; i++) {
    if (rgbdata[i] != -1)
    {
        dos.writeInt(rgbdata[i]);
        dos.flush();
    }
} 
bos.flush();
```

Comment: Why is your code halfway across the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
PNGEncoder encoder = new PNGEncoder(bitmap, true);
byte[] imageBytes = encoder.encode(true);
```

And to get EncodedImage from byte array:

```
EncodedImage fullImage = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to give the link. Here is the PNGEncoder: http://www.mobiyana.com/code/blackberry/PNGEncoder.java